# Vue 3 - Inline component not working in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite

i saw some suggestions but still i can't call component from blade by inline calling

this is my example code

//app.js file:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import TestComponent from "./src/components/test-component.vue";

const app = createApp({});
app.component("test-component", TestComponent);

// component
app.component("example-component", {
    template: `
        <div>
            <slot>GO GO GO</slot>
        </div>`,
});

console.log(TestComponent);
app.mount("#app");

//createApp(TestComponent).mount("#app"); //Works

console.log("Hello");
```

blade:

```
    <div id="app">
        <example-component />
        <test-component />
    </div>

    @vite('resources/js/app.js')
```

test-component.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, Vue in Laravel!</h1>
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
 </template>
  
  <script>
  export default {
    name: 'TestComponent',
    data() {
      return {
        message: 'This is a Test Vue component in Laravel!',
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

i tried different methods by naming of component (like kebab-case or not kebab)

tried to running with cleared Build Cache.. npm run build -- --clearCache

no any errors in console..

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

i have added in vite.config.js

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        vue: "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js",
    },
},
```

after this it works !